# Separating columns from range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to count the number of rows conditionally in Excel sheet.  I wrote the code which calculates numbers in the whole range. However I need to separate results for different columns. For example, now I look at the range  C2:N59, but i want to see results for columns D,E and G,H and so on for every condition. Which Loop should I write for it?
here is my code:

```
Function RabigatorCount()
Dim zelle As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim Rabigator() As Integer
Dim posMonitoring As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim intCounter(9) As Integer
Set zelle = Cells.Find("is_monitoring_relevant")
posMonitoring = zelle.Column
For j = 3 To 16 Step 3
For i = 2 To 59
If Cells(i, posMonitoring).Value = "c" And Cells(i, j + 1).Value < 0 And Cells(i, j + 2).Value < 0 Then
                intCounter(1) = intCounter(1) + 1
                ElseIf Cells(i, posMonitoring).Value = "c" And Cells(i, j + 1).Value = 0 And Cells(i, j + 2).Value < 0 Then
                intCounter(2) = intCounter(2) + 1


            End If 
    Next i
    Next j
   RabigatorCount = intCounter         
   End Function
```

Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0):

If your question is simplified to the following:

*I look at the range C2:N59, but I want to see results for columns D,E and G,H and so on for every condition. Which Loop should I write for it?*

Then this is a possible answer:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim inspectedRange As Range
    Set inspectedRange = Worksheets(1).Range("C2:N59")

    Dim cnt As Long
    For cnt = 1 To inspectedRange.Columns.Count Step 2
        Debug.Print inspectedRange.Columns(cnt).Address
        Debug.Print inspectedRange.Columns(cnt + 1).Address
        Debug.Print "-------------"
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

It prints every 2 columns, starting from `C` and `D` like this:

```
$C$2:$C$59
$D$2:$D$59
-------------
$E$2:$E$59
$F$2:$F$59
-------------
$G$2:$G$59
$H$2:$H$59
-------------
```

And it allows you to work further with these ranges - `inspectedRange.Columns(cnt)` and `inspectedRange.Columns(cnt+1)` the way you want. If you want to use the `j` and `i` in a nested loop, this is a possible way to get the cells and to do something with them:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim inspectedRange As Range
    Set inspectedRange = Worksheets(1).Range("C2:N59")

    Dim j As Long, i As Long, cnt As Long
    Dim col1 As Range
    Dim col2 As Range

    For cnt = 1 To inspectedRange.Columns.Count Step 2
        Set col1 = inspectedRange.Columns(cnt)
        Set col2 = inspectedRange.Columns(cnt + 1)
        For j = 3 To 16 Step 3
            For i = 2 To 59 Step 1
                With Worksheets(1)
                    Debug.Print .Cells(j, col1.Column).Address
                    Debug.Print .Cells(i, col2.Column).Address
                End With
            Next i
        Next j            
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One thing more I have one condition for two colums. " Cells(i, j + 1).Value < 0 And Cells(i, j + 2).Value<0" I want to see separetly  results for every pair of colums

Comment: @Elena - give it a try with the condition, the cells are accessible from here - `Worksheets(1).Cells(j, col1.Column)`.

Comment: Actually it is not exactly that I need. I need the results of conditional counting of the rows in the table, like:   number of rows

Comment: Actually it is not exactly that I need. I need the results of conditional counting of the rows in the table,for instance : if element (i,j) >0 and (i,j+1)>0, then in Columns D,F  (here j=D,j+1=F) we have X rows, and so until  row 16. It should be an array